# React component not updating

Tags: javascript, reactjs

```
export class Person extends Component{

constructor(props){
    super(props);
    this.state = {status:""};
}

componentDidMount(){
    /* get status from database */
    if (this.props.status === "online"){
        document.getElementById("dot").style.background = "green";
        this.setState({status:"online"});
    }
    else if(this.props.status === "offline"){
        document.getElementById("dot").style.background = "red";
        this.setState({status:"offline"});
    }
    else if(this.props.status === "away"){
        document.getElementById("dot").style.background = "yellow";
        this.setState({status:"away"});
    }
}

render(){
    return(
        <ListGroup.Item action variant="success" id="personLi" >
            <Row>
                <Col>
                    <Image id="avatar" src={Avatar} roundedCircle />
                </Col>
                <Col id="profileName">
                    {this.props.name}
                </Col>
                <Col>
                    <span id="dot"></span>
                </Col>
            </Row>
        </ListGroup.Item>
    )
}
```

}

Here is my Person class. I am trying to create a friendbar that has a list of friend names which will get rendered into  components that will have a status bar that will change color based on whether they are online (green) and offline (red). However, when I try to create Person components in my friend bar only the first component has a status bar color of green. Currently, I want to just my status to start off as online which is passed into props.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is not good idea to mixup things. Why you use DOM API together with React?

why do not you want to use the virtual DOM?
And it is an anti-pattern to copy props directly to the component's state.

```
export class Person extends Component{

constructor(props){
    super(props);
    this.state = {status:""};
}

componentDidMount(){
    fetchState().then((status) => this.setState({status}));
}

getStatusColor() {
    switch(this.state.status) {
        case "offline": return "red";
        case "online": return "green";
        case "away": return "yellow";
    }
}

render() {
    return (
        <ListGroup.Item action variant="success" id="personLi" >
            <Row>
                <Col>
                    <Image id="avatar" src={Avatar} roundedCircle />
                </Col>
                <Col id="profileName">
                    {this.props.name}
                </Col>
                <Col>
                    <span style={{backgroundColor: this.getStatusColor()}}></span>
                </Col>
            </Row>
        </ListGroup.Item>
    )
}
```

Comment: also if you want to change DOM somewhere outside take a look at https://reactjs.org/docs/portals.html#gatsby-focus-wrapper

Comment: Thanks a lot this helps a lot

Comment: would fetch state just be a request to get the status?

Comment: it is up to your how to define your async API functions

Answer (score 0):

`document.getElementById` will get the first instance of that ID on the page and change the style. You could handle this in a more React-y way:

```js
export class Person extends Component{
  render(){
    let color = 'green';
    if(this.props.status === 'offline'){
      color = 'red';
    } else if (this.props.status === 'away') {
      color = 'yellow';
    }

    return(
      <ListGroup.Item action variant="success" id="personLi" >
        <Row>
          <Col>
            <Image id="avatar" src={Avatar} roundedCircle />
          </Col>
          <Col id="profileName">
            {this.props.name}
          </Col>
          <Col>
            <span style={{ backgroundColor: color }} />
          </Col>
        </Row>
      </ListGroup.Item>
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: Oh ok that makes sense, thanks a lot. How would I deal with the problem of updating the css for a specific person and not conflict with the id

Comment: @KeeratGrewal you could do exactly what i have posted above and you should be fine